# Pinning package using own repository and apt-get

Tags: apt, repository, localrepository

I created my own repository so I can provide a newer version of a package than the one the Ubuntu repository currently holds. Everything works fine, with the exception that I have to specify the version when installing it:

```
sudo apt-get install package=1.2.1
```

If I don't specify the version, then it will install it from Ubuntu's repository.

I tried to put my repository at the top of the `sources.list` but it doesn't make any difference.

So I'm wondering if there's a flag when building the `.deb` package that will give priority to my repository at all times? or a flag in the actual repository? I'd prefer not having the user to change their `/etc/apt/preferences` to set the priority, nor using `apt-get -t repo`.

I tried to install the `Tor` browser given **[this instructions](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian)** and it does install the latest version from their custom repo. I don't know what they're doing but it does work with only the steps they list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution 1: (using Debian epoch)

Prefix your package version with `1:` so that it will be `1:1.2.1` and thus it will always be seen as a higher version. This is very handy if you build your own modified packages and don't want them replaced by Ubuntu upgrades.

> When comparing two version numbers, first the epoch of each are
>   compared, then the upstream_version if epoch is equal, and then
>   debian_revision if upstream_version is also equal. epoch is compared
>   numerically.

Source: https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Version

### Solution 2 (using Pinning)

To set up AptPreferences for a given package add a new file in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/`.

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/preferences.d/my-package-pin
```

Add add the following lines in that file:

```
Package: my_package
Pin: release o=Ubuntu
Pin-Priority: -10
```

I will prevent Ubuntu repository versions to replace the one provided by your local repo.

To check if the package pin version run:

```
sudo apt-cache policy my_package
```

Visit https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto